# No content jar is creating during maven run with specific execution

Tags: java, maven, packaging

I want to create a jar file running a specific execution Id. I have used the following code..

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <execution>
                        <id>abc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>abc</classifier>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>com/me/process/</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution> 
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>process</classifier>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>com/me/store/</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

From command promt I run mvn clean jar:jar which is creating an empty jar with a warning "JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!".

Could you please guide me.

Comment: You have not compiled anything. Either you run `mvn clean package` to get it done or you can run `mvm clean compile jar:jar`. But why would you like to do that? The jar plugin is bound to the package phase.

Comment: mvn clean install also create a jar as you want

Comment: Don't call maven-jar-plugin via `jar:jar`cause it's bound to package phase so a simple `mvn clean package` should do things.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your reply. But I want to run the execution id "default-cli" and it will create single jar file with the excluded packages. This purpose wouldn't be served if I use mvn clean install/package. it will create multiple jar files